# Algorithm to exclude false positives

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, sample-size

For a list of some hundreds participants where some measure belongs to each participant, if I sample two groups of size $n$ randomly, I want an algorithm that determines **at which sample size** a t-test or such would yield that the samples are not significantly different (e.g. by comparing the means) - as it should be.

Specifically I want to code such an algorithm in Matlab, but I was wondering if there is a smart algorithm for this task.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics) ?